# PHP image compression and resizing

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, image-processing

I finally got my code below to upload an image to my server and record the name of the picture to a database via a post form. However I can't get the image compression down.

It seems that my cheap 1and1 hosting doesn't allocate enough memory for GD library to work. I know there's plupload but I can't figure it out (it uses JavaScript), so any help on how to compress image would be great.

```
<?php
    echo 'start';
    require_once('uploadpath.php');
    echo 'loadedunloadpath';
    $customerid= $_POST['customerid'];
    $image= $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
    $image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];


    if ($_FILES['image']['error'] == 0) {
        echo 'afterimageerror'; 

        echo("Image created and saved successfully.");
        // Move the file to the target upload folder
        $target = GW_UPLOADPATH . $image;
        echo 'targetuploadpath';
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {

            // Connect to the database
            require ('dbconnect.php');
            echo 'dbconnected';
            // Write the data to the database
            $query = "INSERT INTO checkpics (customerid, image) VALUES ('$customerid', '$image')";
            echo 'firstquerycompleted';
            mysqli_query($con, $query);
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: If you ain’t got enough memory for image processing, then you don’t have enough memory for image processing – it’s that simply. Either upgrade to a hosting packet that lets you use more RAM – or only process smaller images (meaning smaller in image dimensions, not file size).

Comment: Image manipulation is pretty resource intensive. Depending on the size of the original image(s), you may not be able to grind through it on your host.

Comment: how much memory do you normally need to get these things accomplished? or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: You can limit the size of the upload and have the user do the compression on their own time.